# Getting one element from a strongly typed data set

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I just learnead to use a strongly typed dataset  along with stored procedures today and things are going very well , except one little problem.I can figure out how to get my data out of a datatable with itarating over it considering the fact that the datable has only one column with one row in it.This is what I have so far:

```
var bookCountAdapter = new CountBooksTableAdapter();
var bookCountDataTable = new BooksAndCategoriesDataSet.CountBooksDataTable();
bookCountAdapter.Fill(bookCountDataTable);
int totalNumberOfBooks = 0;

foreach (BooksAndCategoriesDataSet.CountBooksRow row in bookCountDataTable) {
     totalNumberOfBooks = row.TotalNumberOfBooks;
}

return totalNumberOfBooks;
```

THe store procedure that is used by the dataset is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CountBooks]
AS

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Books
```

Now my curent code works just fine.The problem is that I do not see a reason for itarating over `bookCountDataTable` because I have in it only one element of type int and I only want to retrieve that.

Is there a way I could get that element by writing something similar like this :

```
bookCountDataTable.TotalNumberOfBooks
```

Comment: `bookCountDataTable[0].TotalNumberOfBooks` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure you can do something like this:

```
if(bookCountDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     totalNumberOfBooks = Convert.ToInt32(bookCountDataTable.Rows[0]["TotalNumberOfBooks"]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> because I have in it only one element of type int and I only want to
>   retrieve that.

Access it with the index then like:

```
return bookCountDataTable[0].TotalNumberOfBooks
```

But you **should check the Row count** for the table before.

From your foreach loop it looks like if there are going to be multiple rows in there then the last one's `TotalNumberofBooks` will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you will have a single element you could do something like this

```
int totalNumberOfBooks = bookCountDataTable[0].TotalNumberOfBooks;
```

In any case you shouldn't be using a data set for retrieving a single value. There're better ways to do this as [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

Even on your typed data set you could use the wizard on design view to create a query that returns a single value.